# Rails strong parameters - accepting the virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have ActiveRecord model with persisted name attribute and the virtual attribute.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :name, length: { minimum: 1 }, presence: true

 def virtual_attr=(value)
  # set something
 end

 def virtual_attr
  # get something
 end
end
```

In my controller I am specifying strong parameters:

```
  def my_model_params
    params.permit(:name, :virtual_attr)
  end
```

When I am trying to create/update my model, `my_model_params` only contains a name, whilst I know that `params[:virtual_attr]` has the value that I passed to the controller.  It seems like it is just getting filtered out.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please post what params you are getting on console complete params hash

Comment: @Deepak here is params hash: `{"name"=>"New", "virtual_attr"=>{"enable"=>"false", "start"=>"false"}, "controller"=>"my_model", "action"=>"create"}`.  It's all there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to these params

```
{"name"=>"New", "virtual_attr"=>{"enable"=>"false", "start"=>"false"}, "controller"=>"my_model", "action"=>"create"}
```

You need to change strong params to:

```
def my_model_params
  params.permit(:name, virtual_attr: [:enable, :start])
end
```